# Android 11 root process shows "no valid slot to boot" after flashing patched.img

Tags: root-access, fastboot, google-pixel, android-11

This is the first time I've rooted a phone. I have a Google pixel 4a, running Android 11. I use Ubuntu 20.04 and have a limited knowledge of the command line.

I followed the process at this [xda-link](https://www-xda--developers-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-4a-how-to-unlock-bootloader-root-pass-safetynet/amp/?amp_js_v=a6&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=16044428247832&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xda-developers.com%2Fgoogle-pixel-4a-how-to-unlock-bootloader-root-pass-safetynet%2F) fairly smoothly until the last step before confirming root.

After extracting the stock boot.img, patching it with magisk manager, and running the command:

Fastboot flash boot magisk_patched.img

The Google logo pops up for about 10 seconds and then kicks me back out to fastboot mode. The "reason" displayed on the fastboot menu screen after this says:

No valid slot to boot

Im lost as to why this is happening, and I cant seem to find many people with similar issues. Which leads me to believe that I've missed something simple. Thank you for any insight, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: that [guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4153773&page=14) is far from complete... no mention of flashing right slot.. also encryption will break because no words about you must set preserve force encryption in advanced settings before patching..

Comment: I am thinking of buying this phone and did some reading. Firstly, On Android 11 most people suggest that you use the **canary** version of Magisk (search in Github), though some recent reports say beta Magisk version works. Secondly, it is easier for you to pick up the already patched boot image made using **canary** Magisk from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-4a/development/stock-rooted-boot-images-pixel-4a-t4153249)//Make sure you pick the right boot image // If it works for you, please [self answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).